# What's wrong with this ANTLR grammar?

Tags: antlr, antlr4, context-free-grammar

I want to parse query expressions that look like this:

> Person Name=%John%
>
> (Person Name=John% and Address=%Ontario%)
>
> Person Fullname_3="John C. Smith"

But I'm totally new to Antlr4 and can't even figure out how to parse one single TABLE FIELD=QUERY clause. When I run the grammar below in Go as target, I get

```
line 1:7 mismatched input 'Name' expecting {'not', '(', FIELDNAME}
```

for a simple query like

> Person Name=John

Why can't the Grammar parse FIELDNAME via parsing fieldsearch->field EQ searchterm->FIELDNAME?

I guess I'm misunderstanding something very fundamental here about how Antlr Grammars work, but what?

```
/* ANTLR Grammar for Minidb Query Language */

grammar Mdb;

start : searchclause EOF ;

searchclause
    : table expr
    ;

expr
    : fieldsearch
    | unop fieldsearch
    | LPAREN expr relop expr RPAREN
    ;

unop
    : NOT
    ;

relop
    : AND
    | OR
    ;

fieldsearch
    : field EQ searchterm
    ;

field
    : FIELDNAME
    ;

table
    : TABLENAME
    ;

searchterm
    : STRING
    ;

AND
    : 'and'
    ;

OR
    : 'or'
    ;

NOT
    : 'not'
    ;
EQ
    : '='
    ;

LPAREN
    : '('
    ;

RPAREN
    : ')'
    ;

fragment VALID_ID_START
    : ('a' .. 'z') | ('A' .. 'Z') | '_'
    ;

fragment VALID_ID_CHAR
    : VALID_ID_START | ('0' .. '9')
    ;

TABLENAME
    : VALID_ID_START VALID_ID_CHAR*
    ;

FIELDNAME
    : VALID_ID_START VALID_ID_CHAR*
    ;

STRING: '"' ~('\n'|'"')* ('"' | { panic("syntax-error - unterminated string literal") } ) ;

WS
   : [ \r\n\t] + -> skip
;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking at the tokens produced for that input using `grun Mdb tokens -tokens`. It will tell you that the input consists of two table names, an equals sign and then another table name. To match your grammar it would have needed to be a table name, a *field name*, an equals sign and a *string*.

The first problem is that `TABLENAME` and `FIELDNAME` have the exact same definition. In cases where two lexer rules would produce a match of the same length on the current input, ANTLR prefers the one that comes first in the grammar. So it will never produce a `FIELDNAME` token. To fix that just replace both of those rules with a single `ID` rule. If you want to, you can then introduce parser rules `tableName : ID ;` and `fieldName : ID ;` if you want to keep the names.

The other problem is more straight forward: `John` simply does not match your rules for a string since it's not in quotes. If you do want to allow `John` as a valid search term, you might want to define it as `searchterm : STRING | ID ;` instead of only allowing `STRING`s.

Comment: Perfect reply, I understand the problem now. Thank you so much!